# N-Queens in Java using Stacks, Keeps taking the same route after backtracking

Tags: java

Title pretty much says it all. I've been working on this and just can't figure out a way to prevent it from happening. Perhaps some way to store invalid placements? Or how would I implement a way for it to 'resume' from the last time it was at this row so it doesn't just pick the same value again?

Ignore the while i, its just for debugging. Same with the prints.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class NQueens {

//***** fill in your code here *****
//feel free to add additional methods as necessary

//finds and prints out all solutions to the n-queens problem
public static int solve(int n) {
    //***** fill in your code here *****
    //Scaffolding code from Stacks.pdf
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Create empty stack and set current position to 0
    Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();

    int column = 0;
    int row = 0;

    int solutionsCount = 0;
    int i = 0;
    //Repeat {
    //loop from current position to the last position until a valid position is found //current row
    while (i < 5){

        for(column = 0; column < n ;column++) {
            //if there is a valid position
            System.out.println("Top of for loop");
            System.out.println("Column/index for = " + column + "; Row is: " + row);
            System.out.println("Stack size = " + s.size());
            System.out.println();
            if (isValid(s, column, row)) {
                s.push(column);
                //push the position to stack, set current position to 0 // move to next ro
                row++;
                column = 0;
            }//if
        }//for

        //if there is no valid position
        if(!isValid(s, column, row) || column >= n){
            //if stack is empty, break // stop search
            if(s.size() == 0){
                break; //stop search
            }//if
            //else pop from stack, set current position to next position // backtracking to previous row
            else{
                s.pop();
                column++;
                row--;
            }//else
        }//if

        //if stack has size N { // a solution is found
        if (s.size() == n){
            solutionsCount++;
            printSolution(s);
            //pop from stack, set current position to next position // backtracking to find next solution
            s.pop();
            row--;
            column++;
        }//if

        else {
        }//else
    i++;
    // Make sure to change this when not bug testing for 4x4
    }//end for loop
//update the following statement to return the number of solutions found
return solutionsCount;

}//solve()
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `if(!isValid(s, column, row) || column >= n)` condition be inside the `for` loop???

Comment: Your `for(column = 0; column < n ;column++)` ends after the first `if` condition, and all your backtracking code is in the `if` conditions which lie outside the `for` loop, which is why you cannot backtrack!

Comment: So I just need to move both the other ifs into the for loop?

Comment: Well, that will surely solve your problem that the loop continues with the same values!

Comment: So is the while loop at all necessary or is the for loop the only one that really matters here?

Comment: `for` loop is the only one that matters. Even your question says to ignore the `while` loop

Comment: I have solved the N-Queens once, your backtracking looks fine, your main approach is to go back to the previous row if your placement in the current row fails! You do that outside the for loop, when you are doing `s.pop()`, which makes no sense. If your logic is correct, moving it in would work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like homework, so here are some pointers:

1. You are modifying the `column` variable after the `for` loop.  Obviously, you intend its value to carry over into the next iteration of `while`.  But then the first thing you do when `while` starts again is you set `column` to `0` with `for (column = 0; ....)`, which overrides its value.  What information is `column` supposed to carry from one iteration of `while` to the next?
2. You are setting `column` to `0` inside the `for` loop but it will be incremented to `1` with `column++` before the next `for` iteration.
3. You are using `column` in the `if` statement immediately after the loop.  What do you expect the value of that variable to be after the `for` loop completes?
4. After the `for` loop you have two `if` statements that are trying to check for the same condition -- whether the `for` loop found a solution.  Only the second `if` is much clearer about it.  Do you even need both `if`s?
5. You are putting `column` values into the stack, but when you pop them off the stack, you just discard them.  Don't you have some use for these values?